# Understanding Protocol Inheritance in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, inheritance, protocols

I'll appreciate if anyone can explain the logic behind protocol inheritance. e.g. what does the following mean (UITableView.h):

```
@protocol UITableViewDelegate<NSObject, UIScrollViewDelegate>
```

The following class implementation doesn't work. I have a class View1 (which inherits UIView), with an associated protocol. I have another class, View2 (which inhertits View1). Now i want to inherit the the protocol as well. Can anyone please point me in the right direction.

**Class 1:**

```
@protocol View1Delegate;

@interface View1 : UIView {
    id <View1Delegate> delegate;
    // . . .
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) id <View1Delegate> delegate; // default nil. weak reference

@end

@protocol View1Delegate <NSObject>
- (void)View1DelegateMethod;
@end

@implementation View1

@synthesize delegate;

// . . .
@end
```

**Class 2:**

```
@protocol View2Delegate;

@interface View2 : View1 {
    id <View2Delegate> delegate;
    // . . .
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) id <View2Delegate> delegate; // default nil. weak reference

@end

@protocol View2Delegate <NSObject>
- (void)View2DelegateMethod;
@end

@implementation View2

@synthesize delegate;

// . . .
@end
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Think of it more as composition rather than inheritance.

`@protocol UITableViewDelegate<NSObject, UIScrollViewDelegate>` defines a protocol that includes all the methods of the `NSObject` protocol, the `UIScrollViewDelegate` protocol, as well as any methods defined for the `UITableViewDelegate` protocol. When you subclass and create a new property, you're overriding the type of the superclasses property. To make this work how I think you want, you should declare `View2Delegate` as `@protocol View2Delegate <NSObject, View1Delegate>`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm declaring the protocol as you've mentioned, but the problem i'm facing is with the declaration of id <...>delegate; In View1, I have id <View1Delegate> delegate; with it's associated @property and @synthesize. Since i'm inheriting View1 in View2, when i declare id <View2Delegate> delagete; with it's associated @property and @synthesize, i get an error: "Property 'delegate' attempting to use ivar 'delegate' declared in super class of 'View2'. What's the correct way to handle this situation. Please see the sample classes i've posted above.

Answer (score 0):

It's exactly the same as the inheritance of interfaces in Java (`interface UITableViewDelegate extends NSObject, UIScrollViewDelegate`), C# (`interface UITableViewDelegate : NSObject, UIScrollViewDelegate`), etc.